# Convert jQuery script into a function that can be called within a resize handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll( function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
        $(".header-layout, .top-tier-menu-bar ").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".header-layout, .top-tier-menu-bar").show();
    }
});
```

I wish to turn it into a function so that I can then refer to it using `$(window).resize(function(){...})` as the script is breaking if the user resizes the window.

I have tried wrapping it like this:

```
jQuery.fn.myfunction = function() {
    $(window).scroll( function() {
    if( $(this).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
        $(".header-layout, .top-tier-menu-bar ").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".header-layout, .top-tier-menu-bar").show();
    }
});
}
```

however this causes the jQuery to stop working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you for any help.

Comment: This is an improper use for the JQuery utility function feature. If you want to create an event callback, do that as needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be making it slightly harder than it needs to be with your function. A standard callback as Scott mentioned should do the trick.

```
function checkScrollPosition(){
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > 0 ) {
        $(".header-layout, .top-tier-menu-bar ").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(".header-layout, .top-tier-menu-bar").show();
    }
}

$(window).scroll( function() {
  checkScrollPosition();
});

$(window).resize( function() {
  checkScrollPosition();
});
```

Alternatively, you could use `on` which takes a number of events as its argument:

```
$(window).on("scroll resize", checkScrollPosition);
```

Comment: NOTE: The use of shortcut event methods was deprecated some time ago. Instead always set up even callbacks with `.on()`.

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to say thank you in comments, but thank you @Djave, this solution is ideal for my needs. Appreciate the effort.